# Parsing JSON with jmeter to pass a json array as it is from previous HTTP response to a new HTTP Request

Tags: json, jmeter, post-processor

I had a query regarding fetching a part of json response obtained  from 1st request in jmeter to form a new HTTP request.

I wanted to extract 1 block of info json (as it is) with doubles quotes and colon as a part of 2nd HTTP request.

```
  {
      "details": [
        {
          "outBound": [
            {
              "info": {
                "date": "2016-08-11",
                "class": "M",
                "code": 70,
                "pricing": [
                  {
                    "totalAmount": 68.8,
                    "totalTaxAmount": 30.8,
                    "baseFareAmount": 38.0
                  }
                ],
                "totalAmount": 68.8,
                "totalDuration": 160,
            "referenceNumber": 1,
            "type": "RP",
            "id": 1
          },
          "segments": [
            { 
            "date": "2016-08-11",
            "className": "Standard (W)",
            "code": 70,
            "totalAmount": 68.8,
            "totalDuration": 160,
            "referenceNumber": 1,
            "type": "RP",
            "duration": 160,
            "number": "100"

            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "info": {
            "date": "2016-08-11",
            "class": "M",
            "code": 70,
            "pricing": [
              {
                "totalAmount": 78.8,
                "totalTaxAmount": 40.8,
                "baseFareAmount": 38.0
              }
            ],
            "totalAmount": 78.8,
            "totalDuration": 160,
            "referenceNumber": 2,
            "type": "RP",
            "id": 2
          },
          "segments": [
            { 
            "date": "2016-08-11",
            "className": "Standard (W)",
            "code": 70,
            "totalAmount": 78.8,
            "totalDuration": 160,
            "referenceNumber": 2,
            "type": "RP",
            "duration": 160,
            "number": "200"

            },
             { 
            "date": "2016-08-11",
            "className": "Standard (W)",
            "code": 70,
            "totalAmount": 78.8,
            "totalDuration": 160,
            "referenceNumber": 2,
            "type": "RP",
            "duration": 160,
            "number": "100"

            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "resultCount": {
        "count1": 1,
        "count2": 1
      },
      "displayCount": 2
    }
  ]
    }

>Expected Output: 
    {
          "info": {
            "date": "2016-08-11",
            "class": "M",
            "code": 70,
            "pricing": [
              {
                "totalAmount": 68.8,
                "totalTaxAmount": 30.8,
                "baseFareAmount": 38.0
              }
            ],
            "totalAmount": 68.8,
            "totalDuration": 160,
            "referenceNumber": 1,
            "type": "RP",
            "id": 1
          },
          "segments": [
            { 
            "date": "2016-08-11",
            "className": "Standard (W)",
            "code": 70,
            "totalAmount": 68.8,
            "totalDuration": 160,
            "referenceNumber": 1,
            "type": "RP",
            "duration": 160,
            "number": "100",

            }
          ]
        }
```

I tried using JSON PATH POST Processor, but I was getting the extracted data in the form of `=` in place of colon and string data without double quotes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) instead of this JSON Path one.

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the request which returns above JSON
2. Choose `groovy` in the "Language" dropdown
3. Put the following code into the JSR223 PostProcessor "Script" area:

   ```
   import groovy.json.JsonOutput
   import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

   def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
   def response = jsonSlurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
   def json = JsonOutput.toJson(response.details[0].outBound[0]);

   vars.put("json", json);
   ```
4. Refer extracted value as `${json}` where required

References:

- [Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) - to learn how to work with JSON in Groovy
- [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) - groovy engine installation guide (for JMeter < 3.0) and Groovy scripting in JMeter best practices

Comment: Hi Dmitri.. Thank you for the answer. It is working fine.... But I am not able to maintain the order of json that is extracted, is it possible to extract 1 block of info json (as it is) in the same order as I need to maintain the order for the second HTTP request. ? Thanks in advance.